# How many connection can my website have?

Tags: php, apache, mysql, apache2, linux

As the traffic increased my website hangs quite regularly. The page visit is now averaging 50k per day.

The static page loads fine, but when the page has mysql request it takes too much time to respond. If I restarts the mysql, it will work normal for some time, say 1 hr and the response time starts to get worst.

What could be the issue?

I am not good at server side. Any help is appreciated.

My server configuration are given below.

```
RHEL 5.8 x64
CPU 2 cores
RAM 4GB
HDD 2GB
Apache 2.2
PHP 5.1
MySQL 5.0
```

Do I need to upgrade my system. How many max connection can this configuration support.

I user php with codignator, with db configuration

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: 2GB of hard drive space? sounds like a VPS. Sounds like it might be running out of ram and since it only has 2gb hdd unless you mean 20gb it has 0 swap (Many VPS providers have a non swap policy so when it reaches full up on ram halts can happen). Can you provide more details such as a copy and paste of running top (After a hour and once the halts to start to incur)

Comment: Maybe somebody on serverfault.com could answer this type of question better.